# How to get nested multi-level div returned in Cypress (Material-UI Dialog)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, cypress

I am trying to get the dialog text from a dialog box written using material-ui. It looks a little like this:

```
<div class="dialog"><div> 
   <div>
      <div style="">
         <div style="">
            <div style="">Some Text I want to verify</div>
            <div style""></div>
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I have tried solving this from two sides;

1. trying to add some sort of unique id to the dialogText (i.e. via
   data-test tag), but these divs appear to be generated from within
   the material-ui library.
2. in Jest/Puppeteer I managed to successfully use the
   following (probably brittle) selector to solve the same problem:

   ```
   const dialogText = await page.$eval('[class="dialog"] > div:first-child > div:first-child > div:first-child > div:first-child', e => e.innerHTML);
   expect(dialogText).toBe('Some Text I want to verify');
   ```

I have tried the same sort of (brittle) approach in Cypress:

```
cy.get('.dialog > div:first-child > div:first-child > div:first-child > div:first-child').should(($dialog) => {
  const text = $dialog.text()
  cy.log('nested div tex: ', text);
}
```

But I get null back

I think 1) is generally a more favourable approach as it makes the code more testable (at least in my new-to-cypress state).

However, in the absence of that, 2) should start with the "dialog" class and get whatever text is in that child(x4) div and compare it against an expected value in order to get a decent message if it isn't as expected.

Right now I am struggling to get cy.get and cy.find to return anything.

Thanks

Comment: I recommend using [Cypress Testing Library](https://testing-library.com/docs/cypress-testing-library/intro), then you can easily get it by text.

Comment: `cy.contains('.dialog', 'Some Text I want to verify')` will do it for your simplified example, since text is pulled from all the elements contained in the top level selector.

Comment: Thanks Richard - yes, cy.contains() does work, but isn't optimum in terms of getting a nice "expected x, but got y" type failure. Maybe slightly better would be to be able to get any text under that dialog class and compare it against an expected value... I will have a look for something like that. I will check out Cypress Testing Library also to see if there is any helpers there. The more I think about it, the more I just want to make the app more testable rather than comprimise on the tests.

Comment: Simpler is better - the nesting might change when the Material-UI version changes, then you are working this out once more.

Answer (score -1):

OK, so after much swearing I tried just getting the JS Path from devTools, and that worked...

```
cy.get('.dialog > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > div:nth-child(1)').should('have.text', 'Some Text I want to verify')
```

Weirdly, Cypress did not like

```
cy.get('.dialog > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > div:nth-child(1)').should(($div) => {
  const theText = $div.text();
  cy.log('Log out of dialog Text: ', theText);
});
```

It logged out the text fine but then threw an error "Cannot read property 'text' of null".

This is obviously a brittle selector, but will tide me over untill I work out how to inject data-* attributes in the generated material-ui dialog modal. Probably worth a rephrased question on here from that perspective.

Comment: This is a really brittle implementation. Definitely not recommended.

I find myself in a similar situation with a third party UI component (Ng Zorro) and my data-cy attribute inside the component is not getting recognized. 

Did you find a more robust solution?